# Automate AWS AMI creation without downtime and Data loss

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami, amazon-imagebuilder

I wanted to know is it possible to automate the creation of AMI in AWS without downtime and data loss, if possible how can we achieve it.
I have use system manager-> maintenance window  in which i have set the reboot to true for data integrity, but i need a way so that the data is not lost.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thank-you.

Comment: Can you share details for your storage which storage you are using? EBS or EFS and the type of data which you want to prevent? Is it Database, Files or what?

Comment: Hi @AsfarIrshad I have a ec2 server with 3 EBS volumes attached, need to backup the entire server along with the volumes.

Comment: posted a solution, did it helped?

Answer (score 0):

> Answering it as per comments discussion, question is somehow still vague to me

You have EBS right now. I'm not sure if your Instances are in Same AZ or not. If they are in same AZ then you can use EBS multi attach feature (available for IO volumes only) to share same storage with all of them.
Regarding backup you can choose EBS snapshots

**Ideally my suggestion to you would be create a launch template, use EFS that can be mounted to multiple instances in same region, if you want it across regions then create mount targets. EFS is natively integrated with AWS backup.
Whenever any failover happens or your EC2 crashes for any reason and it goes less than your target capacity, auto scaling would automatically provision a new instance using launch template which would be using same EFS**

Answer (score 0):

> but i need a way so that the data is not lost.

1. if you want to achieve this, then According to [Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-creating-snapshot.html), you need to ensure that application or os is not writing to ebs, which can be managed by either a script or a custom logic.

> You can take a snapshot of an attached volume that is in use. However, snapshots only capture data that has been written to your Amazon EBS volume at the time the snapshot command is issued. This might exclude any data that has been cached by any applications or the operating system. If you can pause any file writes to the volume long enough to take a snapshot, your snapshot should be complete. However, if you can't pause all file writes to the volume, you should unmount the volume from within the instance, issue the snapshot command, and then remount the volume to ensure a consistent and complete snapshot.

if you achieved the above then you can automate the creation, retention, and deletion of EBS snapshots and EBS-backed AMIs it using [Data Lifecycle Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/snapshot-lifecycle.html)

2. I haven't tried this but I think exporting VM to S3 and then automating the entire pipeline with [Ec2 image builder](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/imagebuilder/latest/userguide/vm-import-export.html) should do the trick, you can customise your further images with build components

Refers [importing and exporting](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmexport.html) vm's

**Unfortunately there is not of box solution other than compromising data integrity but you can try above mentioned which can ensure data integrity and automation**

Comment: Thank-you for the help will try it. Edit: but this involves downtime right?

Comment: Upon trying if it solves your purpose, feel free to accept it so that it helps others in the future :)

Comment: sure, can you kindly clarify if this involves the server to be stoped or not?

Comment: if you trying custom logic/script  to ensure data integrity then you need to stop the server because server reboots ignorer to ensure data integrtity which in your case will be done by your script. for vm export there is no mentioned prequisite to stop instance in order to perform export https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmexport.html#vmexport-prerequisites so I dont think so you need to stop your instance. also read condideration for 2) option https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmexport.html#vmexport-limits
Please try it out

Comment: Upon going through the https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmexport.html, I see there are too much limitations, due too which  I may not be able to use it. anyhow I will give it a go...

Comment: I know limitations are there but maybe those limitations will not apply to you